# Get the most common/frequent value for each month

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a table that looks like this:

```
 id | age |       date
----|-----|--------------------
 1  | 18  | 2016-07-1 00:00:00
 2  | 20  | 2016-07-1 00:00:00
 3  | 20  | 2016-07-1 00:00:00
 4  | 22  | 2016-08-1 00:00:00
 5  | 22  | 2016-08-1 00:00:00
 6  | 30  | 2016-08-1 00:00:00
 7  | 25  | 2016-09-1 00:00:00
```

And I need to get the most common age for each month + year.

I have this query so far:

```
$ages = User::selectRaw('age, MONTH(date) as month, YEAR(date) as year, count(*) as count')
        ->groupBy(['age', 'month', 'year'])
        ->orderBy('year', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('month', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

This only gets the count for each age for each month + year. I need something that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "age": 20,
    "month": 7,
    "year": 2016,
  },
  {
    "age": 22,
    "month": 8,
    "year": 2016,
  },
  {
    "age": 25,
    "month": 9,
    "year": 2016,
  }
]
```

i.e. for July (month == 7) 2016 there are two 20s and one 18, so 20 is the most common age. For August 2016, most common is 22, and so on...

What's a good query for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select substr(max(concat(lpad(count,10,'0'),age)),11) as age, month, year
  from (
   select age, MONTH(date) as month, YEAR(date) as year, count(*) as count
     from test6
    group by age, MONTH(date), YEAR(date)
  ) A
 group by month, year
 order by year, month
```

`substr(max(concat(lpad(count,10,'0'),age)),11)` assemble string "count-age", gets maximum (row with maximum count(*)), and cuts the "age" back.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$ages = User::selectRaw('age, MONTH(date) as month, YEAR(date) as year, count(*) as count')
    ->groupBy(['age', 'month', 'year'])
    ->orderBy('year', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('month', 'asc')
    ->havingRaw('count = MAX(count)')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This operation is a bit difficult in MySQL.  Here are three choices:

- Devising a complicated query that does the aggregation twice
- Using variables
- Taking advantage of a "hack"

The third looks like this:

```
select yyyy, mm,
       substring_index(group_concat(age order by cnt desc), ',', 1) as mode
from (select age, year(date) as yyyy, month(date) as mm, 
             count(*) as cnt
      from test6 t
      group by age, MONTH(date), YEAR(date)
     ) t
group by yyyy, mm;
```

The first looks like this:

```
select year(date), month(date), age
from test6 t
group by year(date), month(date)
having count(*) = (select count(*)
                   from test6 t2
                   where year(t2.date) = year(t.date) and
                         month(t2.date) = month(t.date)
                   group by age
                   order by count(*) desc
                   limit 1
                  );
```

Note that this returns somewhat different results from the first query.  This version will return duplicates, if multiple ages are the most common.

Comment: Is it certain that substring_index must return the correct result? I ask because it seems a little counter-intuitive that it's working after the GROUP BY.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . What do you mean "working after the `GROUP BY`?  There are two aggregations in the first query.

Comment: I guess I'm asking if your 'hack' solution is any less 'hacky' than my 'hack' solution.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Yes.  MySQL is explicitly documented to returned values from an *indeterminate* row when columns are included in the `select` but not the `group by`.  Hence, your "hack" solution is not guaranteed to return correct results.  The solutions in this answer produce the correct results, but using string manipulation rather than more typical SQL operations.

Comment: I see. You call your solution a 'hack' because of the trick of casting an integer as a string. I call mine a hack, precisely because of its undocumented, technically unverifiable, and indeterminate nature  (but maybe we have slightly differing definitions of 'hack'  - or maybe I'm just wandering off piste)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to reformat but, in MySQL, a valid query might look like this:

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') yearmonth
            , age
            , COUNT(*) total 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY yearmonth
            , age
     ) a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT yearmonth
            , MAX(total) total 
         FROM 
            ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') yearmonth
                   , age
                   , COUNT(*) total 
                FROM my_table 
               GROUP 
                  BY yearmonth
                   , age
            ) x 
        GROUP 
           BY yearmonth
     ) b 
    ON b.yearmonth = a.yearmonth 
   AND b.total = a.total;
```

Where two ages are tied at the top for a given month, this query will return both.

If 'hack' solutions are allowed, here's a doozy...

```
SELECT yearmonth 
     , age 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') yearmonth
            , age 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY yearmonth
            , age 
        ORDER 
           BY yearmonth
            , COUNT(*) DESC
     ) x 
 GROUP 
    BY yearmonth;
```

In the case of tied results, this solution will pick one result in indeterminate fashion. According to the documentation, it's also not guaranteed to produce a correct result. While in practice it always does, I prefer the first solution.